# Unicode to PDF conversion using iTextSharp not showing text exactly as it is

Tags: c#, pdf-generation, itext, unicode-string

I am using iTextSharp and HTMLWorker to convert an HTML( in string format) with uni code to PDF,here i am using google input tool to type malayalam and the font is kartika,when converting "കോട്ടയം" i am not getting as it is

i am attaching my code here please help if any solution to this issue else suggest any API which can meet this requirement.

```
    protected void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            createPDF("<font face='Kartika'> കോട്ടയം </font>");
        }
        catch
        {

        }
    }
    public void createPDF(string html)
    {
        try
        {

            Document doc = new Document(PageSize.LETTER);

            using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(Path.Combine("Test.pdf"), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
            {
                PdfWriter.GetInstance(doc, fs);

                doc.Open();

                //Sample HTML
                StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
                stringBuilder.Append(html);

                //Path to our font
                string KartikaTff = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.Fonts), "Kartika.TTF");
                //Register the font with iTextSharp
                iTextSharp.text.FontFactory.Register(KartikaTff);

                //Create a new stylesheet
                iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet ST = new iTextSharp.text.html.simpleparser.StyleSheet();
                //Set the default body font to our registered font's internal name
                ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.FACE, "Arial Unicode MS");
                //Set the default encoding to support Unicode characters
                ST.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.BODY, HtmlTags.ENCODING, BaseFont.IDENTITY_H);

                //Parse our HTML using the stylesheet created above
                List<IElement> list = HTMLWorker.ParseToList(new StringReader(stringBuilder.ToString()), ST);

                //Loop through each element, don't bother wrapping in P tags
                foreach (var element in list)
                {
                    doc.Add(element);
                }

                doc.Close();
            }






        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

        }
    }
```

Comment: One of the problems with your code is that you are using the obsolete `HTMLWorker`. You should really use `XMLWorker`. Code examples can be found on http://developers.itextpdf.com/examples/xml-worker, the API reference on http://developers.itextpdf.com/reference/classes. Even though that documentation is for Java, iText and XMLWorker are fully ported to .NET and the API is identical.

Comment: Ignoring HTML for now, I can't get that font to work with iText to start with using just `doc.Add(new Paragraph("\u0d4b", FontFactory.GetFont("Kartika")));`